# Javascript will only work on direct page load

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript file that I can get to work perfectly when you enter the page address directly into a browser, or from a direct link inside an email etc.

However, If the page with the JS is open via a link from somewhere else on the same site, the JS doesn't work. For example, I have that page linked from my homepage, and when the JS page loads, nothing happens - but, if I then refresh the page, it works again.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Here is the code - (it is a random image generator):

edit - the Page address is www.symmonegordon.com/your-card

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--

/*
Random Image Script- By JavaScript Kit (http://www.javascriptkit.com) 
Over 400+ free JavaScripts here!
Keep this notice intact please
*/
 /*
Make note of the URL and make sure its set correct - IMPORTANT
*/
function random_imglink(){
var symimages=new Array()
//specify random images below. You can have as many as you wish
symimages[1]="01.jpg"
symimages[2]="02.jpg"
symimages[3]="03.jpg"
var ry=Math.floor(Math.random()*symimages.length)
if (ry==0)
ry=1
document.write('<img    src="http://www.mattselley.com/symimages/'+symimages[ry]+'" border=0>')
}
random_imglink()
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Don't use `document.write()`.  Instead, use DOM APIs.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply, but this is something I have no experience in. What do i change the document.write to?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate further on what SLaks had started on, you should definitely use DOM APIS. For example, document.querySelector might be a good fit here. For this pretend exercise, lets imagine you have a div with a class of "random-image" on your page.

```
// You can create arrays on the fly in JS with array literal syntax
var images = [
  "http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/golf-1-top-82328.jpg",
  "https://assets.entrepreneur.com/article/1413519079_unsplash-1024x682.jpg",
  "https://images.freeimages.com/images/small-previews/540/dandelion-37-1388001.jpg"
]

function randomImage() {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)
  var randomImageDiv = document.querySelector('.random-image')
  randomImageDiv.innerHTML = '<img src="' + images[random] + '" />'
}

randomImage()
```

Check out the following [Codepen](https://codepen.io/DZuz14/pen/WMwGZJ?editors=1010) as well for further clarification.

Comment: Thank you both for your help - I shall have a good read to implement it all. Im very new to this but want to learn :-)

Comment: Good luck on your quest!