# why does Javascript only work on direct page load

Tags: javascript, dom

I have learned a lot through SO because, normally, if a question is asked, the root cause of the problem becomes very evident. In the case of this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48604378/javascript-will-only-work-on-direct-page-load), the proposed solution doesn't make it clear (at least to me) "why" a page will load correctly if a direct url is used but won't load correctly if it's referenced via a hyperlink. I am running into this same issue and instead of just adding a fix/solution I'd like to know why it's causing a problem in the first place. If a url is placed in a browser tab how is that different from the exact url being hyperlinked? Could someone elaborate to help me understand what is occuring? Thank you.

Comment: Without seeing your code as a [mcve] we can't help you debug it.

Comment: I'm not sure what code to provide here because I don't understand why there would be a difference between a direct url and a hyperlink. I have 1,000+ lines of code and the errors are "Uncaught ReferenceError" which implies scope but why would scope NOT be an issue for a direct url and become an issue only on a hyperlink? I'm not being lazy here, I just don't know what code to provide given the aforementioned lack of understanding of what differences exist between the two methods of loading the page.

Comment: You need to start debugging your code using the browser dev tools (F12). Errors like "Uncaught ReferenceError" will have an actual reason why it's an error, and you haven't told us what that is either. "Uncaught ReferenceError: x is undefined" or "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is undefined" and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I was using dev tools and all the Uncaught referenceError messages are functions (at least at this point). So I moved the offending function into the head section to see if it made a difference and it resolved that error but another function errored in the same way. This led me to believe that scope was - in some way - the issue but I still don't see why scope changes just because the page is referenced by a hyperlink versus a direct url. My hope was that someone could let me know what the difference is so I can do some additional research/learning. Does that help?

Comment: I am new to SO so my question is respectfully asked ... if a question is not answered does it just go dormant? Am I likely to get an answer to this question or do I need to ask again? Thanks.